# Argument passed to when() is not a mock! exception thrown with Spring Boot project which doesn't have @SpringBootApplication/main class

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

My project is a simple spring boot application which doesn't have a main/@SpringBootApplication class. It is used as a dependency library for other modules. I am trying to write the unit tests for the classes present in this project like below and getting the below pasted error. Any quick help is much appreciated.

pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        
        <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
     <!-- junit 5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

As this project doesn't have main class, to get the spring application context using below configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class TestServiceConfig {
@Bean
public TestService productService() {
    return Mockito.mock(TestService.class);
}

@Bean
public MongoDriverService productMongo() {
    return Mockito.mock(MongoDriverService.class);
}
}
```

Below is my test class which is throwing exception. Actual java class has a method called getPlanCode(which takes 6 arguments) and returns void. In this method **mongo** object is used for connecting the db so that I used @InjectMocks on service object.

```
public class ValidationServiceTest {
@Mock
MongoDriverService mongo;

@InjectMocks
TestService service;

@Test
@DisplayName("Test Get Plan Code positive")
public void getPlanCodeTest() {
    doNothing().when(service).getPlanCode(anyString(), anyString(), any(Batch.class), any(BatchFile.class), any(Document.class), anyString());
    
    service.getPlanCode(anyString(), anyString(), any(Batch.class), any(BatchFile.class), any(Document.class), anyString());

    verify(service, times(1)).getPlanCode(anyString(), anyString(), any(Batch.class), any(BatchFile.class), any(Document.class), anyString());
    
}
}
```

Below is the exception

```
12:51:33.829 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@45b4c3a9 testClass = DefaultMedicareBFTAccumsValidationServiceTest, testInstance = com.anthem.rxsmart.service.standalone.batchvalidation.DefaultMedicareBFTAccumsValidationServiceTest@14dda234, testMethod = getPlanCodeTest@DValidationServiceTest, testException = org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service` is not a mock since you are using `@InjectMocks` ( assume you are using `@RunWith(MockitoRunner.class)` or `@ExtendWith` but you are hiding that for whatever reasons).

What `@InjectMocks` does, is create of a new instance of `TestService` and literally inject mocks into it (mocked required dependencies). So service is a real thing, not a mock

IMO this test makes not sense as you are suppose to test your implementation of singular entity contract, not to test mocks...

Your test case and assertions are pointless as it is like "call method A and check if I just called method A" while you should check and validate eg return value of a call, or if some methods of mocks have been called eg if Mongo was queried with proper arguments. I just hope it is a really bad example, not real test scenario

Also test setup is wrong as you show us that you want to use `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` but then you are using `@Mock` in the test which will create brand new mocks for you. In other words - that config is not used at all

Comment: Actually I gathered this knowledge from some articles so it has gaps. Could you please help me with the correct process to follow to write test cases to test my service methods and the mongo calls in them.

Comment: Testing features is a topic as wide as implementing those features so it is not something I can explain your here. Whetever it is a mongo or not, it is a dependency that could be mocked to test your service and if it interacts with dependencies correctly. Try to google out "junit inject mocks example" and read maybe some literature on how to write unit tests (youtube contains some valuable lectures as well)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer just for the developers who are in same understanding state.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Test Get Plan Code positive")
public void getPlanCodeTest() {
    service = new ValidationService(mongo);
    
    Mockito.when(mongo.aggregateIterable("test", pipeline)).thenReturn(tierFilterDocs);
    
    service.getPlanCode("", "", null, batchFile, null, "");
    verify(mongo, times(1)).aggregateIterable("test", pipeline);        
}
```

I have updated my test case so it solves the purpose now. Now no need of the Configuration file as I am mocking the object in test class itself.